# Cannot update Eclipse due to conflicting dependencies

Tags: 11.10, java, updates, eclipse

I installed Eclipse via the Ubuntu repos (I'm on Ubuntu 11.10). Then I added the Indigo repo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/) as only Helios repos were listed as part of the default install. If I go to Help>Check for Updates then a number of updates are listed for install, however when I click Next I get the following error:

```
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JSch UI 1.1.300.dist (org.eclipse.jsch.ui 1.1.300.dist)
    JSch UI 1.1.300.I20110511-0800 (org.eclipse.jsch.ui 1.1.300.I20110511-0800)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
    To: org.eclipse.jsch.ui [1.1.300.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)
    To: org.eclipse.jsch.ui [1.1.300.I20110511-0800]
```

I have tried fully removing eclipse and all config files and re-installing but that doesn't help. I can't find any info from Googling around either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just download the latest release from [eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads/). Many people myself included cannot get past errors when updating or attempting to install software into the eclipse version from the repo's.

Comment: I second that. Same for me. Just download the latest version from the site.

Comment: It's sad that's the only way but of course it does work, thanks all.

Comment: Downloading works. Two questions: (1) what is the 'right' location to put the eclipse folder? I'm putting it in /opt/eclipse - is that what most people do? (2) How would you customize Dash to have an icon to eclipse?

Comment: @Uri ubuntu repo installs it in `/usr/lib/eclipse`

Answer (score 2):

You can run eclipse from ubuntu repositories with user root. Edit the Available Update Sites, because they are not changed since the helios release. Than Check for Updates and install Updates. Afterwards you start eclipse as normal user again.

Comment: This worked for me. I first launched eclipse as root, then removed all update sites from the repo list in preferences, then I added the appropriate site from : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with the Indigo repo. The Debian and Ubuntu eclipse team have a PPA that's more likely to work well: https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team

Answer (score 1):

Updating via root user, made  the upgrade to 3.7.2 possible, at last !

It may seems strange but, considering the binary are in /usr/bin, it is normal the common user can not provide a system wide upgrade.
Starting eclipse via su, and giving it the process the root ID, makes the upgrade possible.

The only other way it could be possible would be via synatpic, **IF** only the repository would have made updates available....